# Lidando com perguntas duplicadas

Tags: debate, proposta-para-faq, perguntas, perguntas-duplicadas

Há muita dúvida em como lidar com perguntas duplicadas. Como tratá-las adequadamente?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Primeiro vamos entender o que é uma pergunta duplicada:

1. **Duplicadas por <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd> e <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>V</kbd><sup>*</sup>**: estas perguntas são por definição exatamente duplicadas. São perguntas deliberamente copiadas que podem ocorrer por várias razões, alguma delas que só o autor da proeza consegue entender. Perguntas assim devem **receber votos negativos e sinalização para a moderação** tomar alguma ação. Tipicamente a pergunta será apagada por se aproximar do abuso do sistema.
2. **Duplicadas acidentais**: elas não são cópias de outra pergunta já existente mas trata exatamente do mesmo assunto. A pergunta usa basicamente as mesmas palavras e pergunta essencialmente a mesma coisa. Todas as medidas para evitar a duplicação, inclusive o esforço do autor, falharam. Os usuários poderão **votar para fechar a pergunta duplicada e criar um link para a pergunta original**. Em alguns casos uma sinalização para a moderação mesclar as perguntas pode ser interessante.
3. **Praticamente duplicadas**: Estes casos são ambíguos. Depende de interpretação porque são perguntas que podem conter pequenas diferenças que fazem a pergunta ser muito parecida mas não exatamente igual. É importante que as tags **ajudem a relacionar as perguntas** parecidas mas quando for interpretado que não se trata de duplicata exata, elas devem permanecer abertas.

É importante eliminar perguntas duplicadas mas também temos que fazer isso com cuidado. Muitas vezes uma pergunta parece duplicada e mas não é. O fato de ser do mesmo assunto não define por si só, a duplicação. **A pergunta só é duplicada se ela produzirá respostas iguais**. Se for possível juntá-las e ninguém notar que algumas respostas de uma pergunta foram dadas no outra.

Fechar perguntas similares mas legítimas é tão ruim quanto deixar duplicadas abertas. Há uma tendência em muitos usuários de sair fechando perguntas que tem a mais leve semelhança, mesmo que elas sejam, de fato, diferentes.

Pode parecer paradoxal, mas **o que define melhor se uma pergunta é duplicada, são suas respostas**. Não necessariamente respostas postadas, mas as possíveis respostas que podem ser inferidas.

Dito isto, devemos observar que uma pergunta A é duplicada de outra pergunta B, quando a pergunta B recebeu uma resposta relevante que efetivamente responde o que foi perguntado. Não importa qual pergunta foi postada primeiro. Uma pergunta só está completa com uma resposta. Se a pergunta A foi feita primeiro, mas a pergunta B, que é duplicada da A, recebeu uma resposta relevante antes da pergunta A, então a A é que é a duplicata e é ela que deve ser fechada. Não podemos fechar uma pergunta com resposta relevante e deixar a pergunta sem resposta aberta.

Claro que em muitos casos a segunda pergunta nem terá a chance de obter uma resposta. Mas surpreendentemente, é comum receber uma resposta quando a original não conseguiu.

Podemos considerar que perguntas perfeitamente duplicatas são quase como unicórnios. Você pensa que viu um mas você se enganou.

Não entenda errado. Ter muitas perguntas duplicadas, principalmente ter várias versões da mesma pergunta não é algo bom, mas se há alguma diferença, que pode produzir algo diferente, podemos conviver com isso, e vamos aprender alguma coisa um pouco diferente. Mesmo trabalhando com uma área exata, a quantidade de variações do que cada assunto pode render, torna virtualmente infinita a quantidade de perguntas possíveis.

Outro **recurso que pode ser usado para evitar a duplicação é a edição** feita pelo autor ou por outro usuário, embora o autor tenha mais chances de fazer uma edição consistente com o que ele quer. Mas se ele próprio reconhece que o que ele queria saber já foi respondido, a duplicação fica mais facilmente caracterizada.

O que você pode fazer quando encontrar uma pergunta duplicada aberta e o que deve ser evitado?

- **Não responda a pergunta que já tem uma resposta em outro lugar**. Pode ser tentador porque você ganha reputação e está ajudando alguém obter uma resposta. Mas a atitude correta é fechar a pergunta e "linkar" para a pergunta onde existe uma resposta. As respostas contidas aqui no site precisam ser canônicas.
- **Para fechar uma pegunta duplicada ela precisa ser realmente duplicada**. Quando há variações, quando uma pergunta está pedindo por algo a mais que outra, não há duplicação.
- **É permitido editar uma pergunta para torná-la mais geral ou diferente de outra**. A edição é a primeira opção para ajudar a melhorar o site. Fechar uma pergunta deve ser a última.
- **Ajude montar uma biblioteca de respostas "matadoras"**. Se você vê uma pergunta sendo feita várias vezes, crie uma resposta canônica, absoluta e aí temos uma situação mais fácil para fechar as perguntas duplicadas, porque já existe uma resposta no site.

Lembre-se que o objetivo do site é ter respostas excelentes, por isso as respostas são fundamentais para determinar se uma pergunta é duplicada ou não. Uma pergunta não pode ser duplicada de outra que não responde o que está sendo perguntado, seja por falta de respostas, seja porque as respostas não cobrem exatamente o que foi perguntado.

Qual é a vantagem de fechar uma pergunta que não foi respondida em qualquer outro local do site? A pergunta nova pode ter melhor sorte, e frequentemente tem.

Então aprenda a amar a duplicação de perguntas sem perder de vista a necessidade de manter o site limpo de ruído.

---

Este texto foi baseado em posts do blog oficial: [Handling Duplicate Questions](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2009/04/handling-duplicate-questions/), [Dr. Strangedupe: Or, How I Learned to Stop Worrying And Love Duplication](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/11/dr-strangedupe-or-how-i-learned-to-stop-worrying-and-love-duplication/) e [The Wikipedia of Long Tail Programming Questions](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2011/01/the-wikipedia-of-long-tail-programming-questions/)

<sup>* Me desculpem os usuários de outros sistemas, mas todo mundo entende essa referência</sup>