# Usuário com múltiplas perguntas similares

Tags: debate, comunidade, perguntas-duplicadas, novos-usuários

Após editar a pergunta com título [Espaço indesejado ao adicionar uma Google Font](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/95256/ao-adicionar-uma-google-font-aparece-um-espa%C3%A7o-de-1px-indesejado) do usuário [Harison](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/users/11615/harison), notei que o mesmo já havia feito outras 3 perguntas com conteúdo relacionado a "1px sobrando ao final do rodapé".

Segue lista com demais perguntas:

1: [Espaço indesejado ao adicionar uma Google Font](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/95256/ao-adicionar-uma-google-font-aparece-um-espa%C3%A7o-de-1px-indesejado);

2: [Seria isso um bug? (Internet Explorer 10)](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/86465/seria-isso-um-bug-internet-explorer-10);

3: [Que espaço desconhecido é este? [duplicada]](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/90065/que-espa%C3%A7o-desconhecido-%C3%A9-este);

4: [Espaço indesejado de 1px no Internet Explorer](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/88401/espa%C3%A7o-indesejado-de-1px-no-internet-explorer);

Acredito que talvez essas perguntas seja classificada como **praticamente duplicadas**, conforme a resposta correta dada a publicação [Lidando com perguntas duplicadas](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/607/lidando-com-perguntas-duplicadas), já que todas estão relacionadas ao navegador *Internet Explorer* e a duvida é sempre em relação a "1px de sobra", que acredito eu, em todos os casos possa ser resolvido utilizando *CSS Resets*, como descrito nos comentários da pergunta 1 e 2 e em uma resposta da pergunta 4.

Pois bem, como sou novo aqui, ainda tenho algumas dúvidas em relação ao funcionamento do Stack e **gostaria de saber quais são as medidas a serem tomadas nesse caso em específico**.

É necessário sinalizar as demais perguntas desse usuário como duplicada mesmo elas sendo parcialmente duplicadas; pedir para o usuário juntar as perguntas relacionadas em uma unica para poder efetuar uma resposta concreta a partir de todas ou deixar que o usuário continue fazendo perguntas similares sem efetuar respostas como dito no seguinte trecho "Não responda a pergunta que já tem uma resposta em outro lugar" da mesma publicação [Lidando com perguntas duplicadas](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/607/lidando-com-perguntas-duplicadas)?

Qual a atitude a ser tomada em relação ao usuário? Ele deve ser orientado?

Comment: 1 - Vir ao meta expor a situação ✓
2 - Orientar o usuário para que ele não crie perguntas iguais
3 - Sinalizar as perguntas como duplicadas.

Comment: Rafael podes dizer ao usuário para não criar perguntas iguais, que pode sim editar a pergunta e altera-la. Agora podes também colocar numa das perguntas dele o link para esta.